# list merging in nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following list:

```
[['a', [0, 1]], ['b', [2, 3]], ['c', [4, 5]]]
```

I want to change it to:

```
[['a', 0, 1], ['b', 2, 3], ['c', 4, 5]]`
```

How can I do it in Python 3 using list comprehension?

Comment: `res = [[i] + j for i, j in L]`

Comment: Just curious: how this question is too broad? This is a very specific problem that I faced today. And as for the methods to solve a specific problem: I think there are always multiple ways in every programming language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Python 3.5+, you can use unpacking in a list declaration. Use that inside a list-comprehension:

```
lst = [['a', [0, 1]], ['b', [2, 3]], ['c', [4, 5]]]

new_lst = [[x, *more] for x, more in lst]

print(new_lst) # [['a', 0, 1], ['b', 2, 3], ['c', 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Will accept as soon as I can. I need to learn those * and ** s now in Python.

Comment: @anotherone I believe being able to use * in a list like this is only possible since 3.5. It's a cool feature that is definitely worth learning

Comment: Readers, note that this list unpacking is a 3.5+ feature.

Comment: Thanks, Olivier!

Answer (score 4):

Using a list comprehension AND **without** the unpacking operator `*`, here is my easily readable and understandable solution:

```
myList = [['a', [0, 1]], ['b', [2, 3]], ['c', [4, 5]]]
newList = [[x, y, z] for x,[y,z] in myList]
print(newList)
# [['a', 0, 1], ['b', 2, 3], ['c', 4, 5]]
```

Quite simple, isn't it ?
And now, using the unpacking operator `*`, it is even shorter but a bit less understandable if you have to learn about this operator (same answer as @Olivier Melançon):

```
myList = [['a', [0, 1]], ['b', [2, 3]], ['c', [4, 5]]]
newList = [[x, *y] for x,y in myList]
print(newList)
# [['a', 0, 1], ['b', 2, 3], ['c', 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
l_new = [[ll[0]] + ll[1] for ll in l]
```

Output:

```
>> [['a', 0, 1], ['b', 2, 3], ['c', 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lambda function that flattens a list of lists. You can then use it in a list comprehension to iterate through the outermost layer of the list of lists of lists.

```
flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

# the example list
lst = [['a', [0, 1]], ['b', [2, 3]], ['c', [4, 5]]]
final = [flatten(l) for l in lst]
```

outputs:

```
>>> final
[['a', 0, 1], ['b', 2, 3], ['c', 4, 5]]
```

Comment: It works, but that implicitly assumes that the first element is a string of length 1, this is a big caveat.

Comment: thanks, with caveat. :)

Comment: @OlivierMelançon yeah that is definitely a good point. I honestly didn't really think about that.

Comment: @GrantWilliams really looking forward for the day we will be able to do `flatten = lambda l: [*item if isinstance(item, list) else item for sublist in l]`

Comment: @OlivierMelançon for flattening a regular list of lists (without strings) i think `sum(lst, [])` is really neat

Comment: @GrantWilliams it is for small lists, but it gets very inefficient for longer ones since it keeps an intermediate list at all time and thus is O(n^2) instead of a single traversal O(n) algorithm

Comment: @OlivierMelançon oh its terrible for performance, but its my favorite simply because i think its cool. The same way its fun to chain a bunch of itertools functions together instead of just using list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

```
old_list = [['a', [0, 1]], ['b', [2, 3]], ['c', [4, 5]]]
new_list = list(map(lambda x: [x[0]] + x[1], old_list))
```

`new_list` is what you are looking for.

Comment: i was sure that a lambda could be defined to solve this, but was not sure how. thanks!

Comment: You can also use a reduce: `from functools import reduce; new_list = reduce(lambda y, x: y + [[x[0]] + x[1]], old_list, [])`